# Examples of properties where there are provably no non-trivial necessary and sufficient conditions.

Tags: logic

A significant fraction of mathematical research is geared towards finding necessary and sufficient conditions for some property $P$ in some class $C$. So, for example, in the class of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, there is the question of finding necessary and sufficient conditions for a function to be differentiable. In some cases, mathematicians can't find any "non-trivial" condition. Maybe they simply haven't tried hard enough, but perhaps it could simply be that there are no non-trivial necessary and sufficient conditions for that property. I am interested in an instance of a property $P$ for which there provably are no "useful", "non-trivial" necessary and sufficient condition, if there even is such an instance. Of course, there would first have to be a rigorous definition of a useful necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: "Necessary and sufficient conditions for $P$" just means "expression equivalent to $P$", so I think this is too vague to be a real question unless you clarify what "useful" means. If you mean something related to [computability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability) or [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory), there are plenty of examples in those fields of properties that are not (efficiently) computable.